# Pushing Firebase events To a Table View

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am trying to take some events from firebase and add them to a table view for the user to see. My current code looks like this:
[image]

For some reason, the events are only showing up when I print them in the closure (ref.child("Events") part), but outside, it is only showing the "hello" I pushed. Please help me fix this issue, preferably with actual code.

Comment: As of site policy it's better to post code as text not image

Comment: It appears your tableView may not be connected to the controller. See the circle next to the `@IBOutlet` for your tableView? That should have a solid dot in it to show it's connected. I would delete that line and drag a new connection to the controller. When that's done it should look like this `@IBOutlet weak var tblEvents: UITableView!`. I used your exact code and it's working for me with that change. However, see @Sh_Khan answer as it's generally correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload after the for loop

```
self.tblEvents.reloadData()
```

Also put these 2 lines at the beginning of `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tblEvents.dataSource = self
self.tblEvents.delegate = self
```

Comment: Crazy as it sounds, the code in the question works - I am using it now. Setting the  NSTableViewDataSource and delegate appears to trigger a reloadData which calls `numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView)`. Actually, as a test, I have a totally separate app were I manually click a button to set the dataSource and delegate for a tableView and sure enough, when the button is clicked, the tableView reloads.

Comment: Ah. [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1531866-datasource) *Setting the data source invokes tile().* and then *func tile()
Properly sizes the table view and its header view and marks it as needing display.*

Answer (score 0):

Please reload your evens table view in view did load after loop like I have done in below code,

```
ref.child(“Events”).observe(.value, with: { (data) in 
    let events = data.value as! [String:[String:Any]]

For (_, value) in events {
    self.eventsArray.append(value[“EventTitle”]! as! String)
})

// add this line in your code
tblEvents.reloadData()
```